# Spring Integration - MongoDB inbound channel reading the same data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-integration

I need to Query the data from mongoDB using spring integration, I can able Query the data from MongoDB, but the same data is returned more than once,

```
<bean id="mongoDBFactory"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo">
            <bean class="com.mongodb.Mongo">
                <constructor-arg name="host" value="localhost" />
                <constructor-arg name="port" value="27017" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test" />
    </bean>

    <int:channel id="controlChannel"/>

    <int:control-bus input-channel="controlChannel"/>

    <int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter
        id="mongoInboundAdapter" channel="splittingChannel" auto-startup= "false" 
        query="{_id:1}" 
        collection-name="order" 
        mongodb-factory="mongoDBFactory">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="10000"  max-messages-per-poll="1000"/>
    </int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:splitter input-channel="splittingChannel" output-channel="logger"/>

    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="WARN"/>
```

I am using the control channel to start and stop, 
please help me how can i stop the inbound-channel-adapter once the Query is completed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `transaction-synchronization-factory` to modify or remove documents instead of stopping Adapter. See [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mongodb.html#mongodb-inbound-channel-adapter) for more info.

Comment: I don't need to remove or modify a document in database, I Just want to read all documents matching the query @Artem Bilan

Comment: Well, ok. Consider to use then `<int-mongo:outbound-gateway>`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.M6/reference/html/mongodb.html#mongodb-outbound-gateway. Or just `MongoTemplate` directly. However you can use the same transaction sync approach to stop polling Channel Adapter